# textstat_entropy in quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda

I am using quanteda for my research project. I have a corpus that consists of 654 documents. I have build a dfm that has 6900 features.

Can someone explain please what do the values of entropy mean, when the function was run for features?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's the standard definition from information theory that is

-1 * sum{p(x)log(p(x)}

where the p(x) is the relative frequency of the feature (in other words, proportion of times that feature occurs in a document).

By default, this is computed for features within documents. If `margin = "features", then it transposes the dfm and computes the entropy of document frequency across features.

You can read more about entropy in many sources, starting with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).